# Подсчёт количества элементов, общих для обеих последовательностей

Tags: c#, массивы

Даны две последовательности целых чисел. В каждой из последовательностей встречаются только различные числа. Определите сколько и каких членов первой последовательности совпадают с членами второй.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что работа за автора.

Comment: @kff да ладно вопрос на две строки, но зато востребованный в поиске

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = {2, 3, 4};

var result = a.Intersect(b); //result - совпадающие члены
int count  = result.Count(); //count  - количество совпадающих членов
```

[RTFM !!!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А лучше a.Intersect(b).ToArray(); 
или new HashSet<int>(a.Intersect(b));
а ещё лучше и массивы a и b в HashSet переделать

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, а потом долго-долго объяснять "что есть такое ХэшСет"? :)

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, чем лучше?